# gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, sockets

I hope to access the text file from the following url:

http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt

My code is

```
import socket

socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080)
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('http://www.pythonlearn.com', 80))
mysock.send('GET http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')
```

I keep getting an error: `gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`

Can you help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: check your internet connection and check if your DNS servers are working. That error means that python couldn't resolve the address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `mysock.connect(('http://www.pythonlearn.com', 80))`, the first element in the tuple should be just the host name (or address), without 'http://'.

So `mysock.connect(('www.pythonlearn.com', 80))` should work.

Incidentally, `socket.getaddrinfo('127.0.0.1', 8080)` would get the address information for your local host, not the server you want to contact; so this statement seems unnecessary.

Comment: I tried this and I get a new error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Your new error comes from the last statement.  You're using Python 3, so any data sent or received through the network must be bytes, not string.  This can be fixed by putting a letter `b` in front of the string literal: `mysock.send(b'GET http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/intro-short.txt HTTP/1.0\n\n')`

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: I tried the code also without the HTTP in the connect method and still get the same error. Any help ?